# payload is invalid for laravel_session decrypt

Tags: laravel, session, ratchet

I'm trying to decrypt laravel_session but the following error occur:

```
An error has occurred: The payload is invalid.
```

simply I'm using Rachet and I'm trying to call the authorized user, so I got the cookies in httpRequest using the following:

```
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = new Client();
        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId]->conn = $conn;


        $cookiesRaw = $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie');

        $cookies = [];
        if(count($cookiesRaw))
        {
            $cookies = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_header($cookiesRaw)[0]; // Array of cookies
        }

 // Get the laravel's one
        $laravelCookie = $cookies[Config::get('session.cookie')];

$idSession = Crypt::decrypt($laravelCookie);
        echo "\n cookie is ";
        print_r($idSession);

}
```

The `Crypt::decrypt($laravelCookie);` is causing the error, I've tried to use:

```
    $cookie_contents = json_decode( base64_decode( $laravelCookie, true ));
    $value = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->value );
    $iv = base64_decode( $cookie_contents->iv );
    $clear = unserialize( \openssl_decrypt($value, \Config::get( 'app.cipher' ), \Config::get( 'app.key' ), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
    echo "Cookie contents (Session ID): $value\n";
```

but it is also causing The payload is invalid.

How can I decrypt this laravel_session in order to get user session id !

I want to get the Auth user via this session.

I've searched a lot in stack-overflow and google, but all the cases didn't match mine.

> Note: I'm using SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: use `\Session::getId()`

Comment: I assume this is some sort of websocket application since you are using ratchet? I'm not sure if you need the session id, or the authenticated users information, in any case what you could do is encrypt whatever user data you need, then send it through to your websocket(ratchet) server.

Comment: @adam Thank you !, now how can i get the user object using this session ?
Am just trying to get the app user in webscoket using back end, any suggestion ?

Comment: Yes you can get the user, instead of sending the session id through, send the user id. Then use `User::find($userid);` on your websocket server side.

Comment: @adam but this will be vulnerable !, I mean if i sent the user id from the front-end to websocket, the user can manipulate his id and steal another user identity !
i believe user id should be sent in back end using sessions, am i wrong ?

Comment: Encrypt it before you send it.

Comment: @adam still, he can encrypt a new id and send it to websocket.

Comment: Encryption is done server side, with a key only the server knows about. If the user did encrypt anything, it would be incorrect, and laravel would throw a `DecryptException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides a way to grab your session id:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

$sessionid = Session::getId();
```